# Fetching Data from API using NextJS and Material UI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am trying to create dynamic pages that shows individual book details (i.e. title/author etc) on a separate page based on a query string of the **"id"** of each book. However, I am having difficulty in understanding how to make a request to a API endpoint using NextJS that will get the book details based on its **"id"**. I would like to use Material UI as a UI Framework.

**ISSUE**:  When I run `npm run dev` the book page loads but the book's "props" are not being passed along to the `BookAttributes` component. The `console.log(book)` I added in the book page is `undefined` and the `console.log(title)` in `BookAttributes` is undefined as well.

1. I've tested the API endpoint in POSTMAN and it appears to work.
2. When I refactor the same code using Semantic UI-React instead of Material UI, the book pages load correctly.
3. I am using the NextJS Material UI starter template from the Material UI website as a baseline.

I am fairly new to NextJS and Material UI so your assistance and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help on this!

Here is the code I have so. I have tried to keep in clean and simple.

**BOOK PAGE** (within 'pages' directory)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import BookAttributes from '../components/Book/BookAttributes';

function Book({ book }) {

    console.log(book)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Book Page</h1>
            <BookAttributes {...book} />
        </>
    )
}

Book.getInitalProps = async ({ query: { _id } }) => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/book';
    const payload = { params: { _id }}
    const response = await axios.get(url, payload)
    return { book: response.data }
}

export default Book;
```

**BOOK API ENDPOINT** (within 'pages/api' directory)

```
import Book from '../../models/Book';
import connectDb from '../../utils/connectDb';

connectDb()

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { _id } = req.query
    const book = await Book.findOne({ _id })
    res.status(200).json(book);
}
```

**BOOK ATTRIBUTE COMPONENT** (within 'components' directory)

```
import React from 'react';

function BookAttributes({ title }) {

    console.log(title)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
        </>
    )
}

export default BookAttributes;
```

Comment: Which version of nextjs are you using? If you are using next 9.3 or later, I suggest using the `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` for data fetching instead of `getInitialProps`.

Comment: Thank for your help on this. Yes, I am running NextJS 9.3. As I am very new to NextJS can you please provide an example of how to use "getServerSideProps" and "getStaticProps" in my code above? I tried to use the examples on the NextJS website but I was unable to get it to work. Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you testing on `http://localhost:3000/book?id=something` or `http://localhost:3000/book?_id=something`?

Comment: @GregoryWiley Yes sure, but first you need to understand how `dynamic routing` works and also when to use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`. That is why I suggest you go through the basics in the nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) and also see the  [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes) section.

Comment: @subashMahapatra Good point. I agree. I am working through the NextJS tutorial right now and will focus on the dynamic routes section. If you have any other code examples, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @GregoryWiley I have provided both examples of server-side-rendering and static-site-generation in the answer. Please let me know if you had any trouble implementing the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using dynamic routes here if you want to work with data-fetching methods like `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`.

You can create a page like `pages/book/[id].js`. But to generate the page you have to decide what data-fetching method you want to run. If the data for the page doesn't change very often you can choose to use static-site-generation using `getStaticProps` which will generate the pages at build time. If the data will be changing a lot you can either do server-side-rendering using `getServerSideProps` or fetch the data client-side.

Here is an example for your use-case that you can use for server-side-rendering using `getServerSideProps`, keep in mind the API call inside `getServerSideProps` might fail so you should have appropriate error handling.

In `pages/book/[id].js`

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import BookAttributes from '../components/Book/BookAttributes';

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
   const bookId = ctx.params?.id
   const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/book';
   const response = await axios.get(url, { params: { _id: bookId} })

   return {
      props: {
        book: response.data
      }
   }

}

function Book({ book }) {
   return (
      <>
        <h1>Book Page</h1>
        <BookAttributes {...book} />
     </>
    )
}

export default Book;
```

**Using static-site-generation**
Because the page is dynamic you have to provide a list of paths for which nextjs will generate the pages. You can do that by exporting an async function called `getStaticPaths`.

in `pages/book/[id].js`

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import BookAttributes from '../components/Book/BookAttributes';

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  // here you have two options if you know all the ids of the books
  // you can fetch that data from the api and use all the ids to generate
  // a list of paths or show a fallback version of page if you don't know all
  // ids and still want the page to be static
  // Pseudo code might look like this
  const res = await axios.get('api-endpoint-to-fetch-all-the-books')

  const paths = res.data.map(book => ({ params: { id: book.id }}))

  return {
     paths,
     fallback: false
  }
}

export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
   const bookId = ctx.params?.id
   const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/book';
   const response = await axios.get(url, { params: { _id: bookId} })

   return {
      props: {
        book: response.data
      }
   }

}

function Book({ book }) {
   return (
      <>
        <h1>Book Page</h1>
        <BookAttributes {...book} />
     </>
    )
}

export default Book;
```

The `fallback` property in the returned value of `getStaticPaths` is somewhat important to understand. If you know all the necessary `id` for the pages you can set the `fallback` to `false`. In this case nextjs will simply show a `404` error page for all the paths that were not returned from the function `getStaticPaths`.

If `fallback` is set to `true` nextjs will show a fallback version of page instead of a `404` page for the paths that were not returned from the `getStaticPaths` function. Now where should you set `fallback` to true? Let's suppose in your case new books are added to the database frequently, but the data for the books doesn't change very often so you want the pages to be static. In this case, you can set `fallback` to `true` and generate a list of paths based on avaliable book ids. For the new books nextjs will first show the fallback version of the page than fetch the data based on the id provided in the request and will send the data as JSON which will be used to render the page in the client.

Comment: Good morning @subashMahaptra Thank you very much for your detailed answered and overall help. I will go line by line and study your example for better understanding. Your example and the tutorial from NextJS has helped me become a better JavaScript developer.

Comment: @GregoryWiley Here is a list of [examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples) provided by nextjs in the repo. These examples can also help when you are trying to implement some other library in your app that requres some additional setup.